# Simplify queries on two tables with identical structures

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

These two queries are identical except for the table being queried. What is the best way for me to simplify this to eliminate the duplicated code?

```
        //These two queries are identical except for the table name
        var values = //Check for analog values
        from a in historianDB.tblActualValueFloats
        where a.PointSliceID == pointSliceID
        where a.UTCDateTime >= startDate && a.UTCDateTime < endDate.AddDays(1)
        orderby a.UTCDateTime
        select new Record(a.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime(), a.ActualValue);

        if (values.Count() == 0)//If no analog records exist, check for digital values.
        {
            values =
            from a in historianDB.tblActualValueDigitals
            where a.PointSliceID == pointSliceID
            where a.UTCDateTime >= startDate && a.UTCDateTime < endDate.AddDays(1)
            orderby a.UTCDateTime
            select new Record(a.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime(), a.ActualValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get them much simpler than that other than perhaps using a union and then sorting it out in memory, but the code will be ugly.

You have a pretty clean way of doing it there, bearing in mind that the schema of the tables does differ slightly.

The only optimisation I would recommend is instead of doing a .Count()==0, try using .Any().

That will translate to an 'Exists' in SQL, which is more efficient than counting, as it returns as soon as it finds a record rather than traversing the table to count them.